# Java configuration and dependency injection (akin to Springs IoC vs. Weld / Guice)

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection, jboss-weld

Lets say I have a class `ListCreator` which I want to configure. I want to be able to tell it the sort order and the how to output my table. Therefore I have the boolean `sortDescending` property and the `TableWriter` interface which is implemented by `PdfTableWriter` (but also by `XlsTableWriter`).
In this example I think configuration and DI go hand in hand. I would like to write something like this Spring (pseudo) example:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="ListCreator" class="ModularListCreator">
        <property name="tableWriter">
            <ref local="TableWriter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="sortDescending">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="TableWriter" class="PdfTableWriter"> </bean>
</beans>
```

Now Spring can do this, but it seems like Weld & Guice can not. Weld for example lets you choose alternatives in the beans.xml, but only for the whole application. What if I want to have one `ListCreator` for PDFs and another one for XLS at the same time?

I do not get the scope of Weld and Guice at the moment, as they don't seem to allow much of a configuration. The seem to only alleviate the need to write `new` or to implement your own factories. EJB injection does the same for example, which is nice, but where is the whole configuration part (choosing which instance with what parameters I actually want where).

Coming to the real point: I do **not** want to use Spring as it seems to be overhead. I much rather use something clean and small at best specified by a JSR. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Guice actually gives you a lot of power for configuration. Assuming I'm understanding you correctly, here's a simple example of one way you could do this in Guice, using a provider method in a module.

```
protected void configure() {
  bind(TableWriter.class).to(PdfTableWriter.class);
}

@Provides
protected ListCreator provideListCreator(TableWriter tableWriter) {
  ModularListCreator result = new ModularListCreator();
  result.setTableWriter(tableWriter);
  result.setSortDescending(true);
  return result;
}
```

There are other ways too, including making `setSortDescending` use a binding annotation:

```
@Inject public void setSortDescending(
    @Named("sortDescending") boolean sortDescending)
```

and then binding that property:

```
protected void configure() {
  bind(TableWriter.class).to(PdfTableWriter.class);
  bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("sortDescending")).to(true);
  bind(ListCreator.class).to(ModularListCreator.class);
}
```

Comment: @samy-delux: That's not an issue if you do a build of your code to deploy a change. Are you often changing the XML of a deployed instance without a new build? Anyway, it's relatively easy to pull out things you want to be able to reconfigure without compiling. For example, you could put "sortDescending=true" in a properties file and use Names.bindProperties to bind that from the file.

Comment: While it seams reasonable to rebuild the project when changing the internal behavior (switching implementations of classes) I still think that how Spring does this in a config file is much cleaner. How would I for example configure properties for multiple `ListCreator`s? That properties file would get messy. Isn't there anything else outside of Spring?

Answer (score 0):

For CDI, checkout Seam Solder. It adds the ability to easily configure Managed Beans from an xml file. Judging by the close relationship between the Seam and Weld teams, this mechanism probably has a good chance of making it into a future JSR.

Answer (score 0):

[InPUT](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT) offers a way if you want a flexible description-based solution. I created the whole example, and added it to the [example section](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT/tree/master/Java/Source#stackoverflowexample).

The code is minimal with:

```
Design config = new Design("config.xml");
ListCreator creator = config.getValue("ListCreator");
```

assuming you have a config.xml InPUT *design* which contains the settings in InPUT syntax:

```
<SValue id="ListCreator">
    <NValue id="SortDescending" value="false"/>
    <SValue id="TableWriter" value="Xls"/>
</SValue>
```

For this to work, you have to define the *design space* as follows:

```
<SParam id="ListCreator">
    <NParam id="SortDescending" type="boolean" />
    <SParam id="TableWriter">
        <SChoice id="Xls"/>
        <SChoice id="Pdf"/>
    </SParam>
</SParam>
```

You now tailor the programming language independent design space to your Java implementation in a *code mapping*:

```
<Mapping id="ListCreator" type="test.ListCreator" constructor="TableWriter SortDescending"/>
<Mapping id="ListCreator.TableWriter" type="test.TableWriter"/>
<Mapping id="ListCreator.TableWriter.Xls" type="test.XlsTableWriter"/>
<Mapping id="ListCreator.TableWriter.Pdf" type="test.PdfTableWriter"/>
```

From here, extend and customize at free will without touching the code. You mention the case with multiple ListCreator instances. You would have to make 3 changes:

1) design space:

```
<SValue id="ListCreator" type="[]">
```

2) design (for example):

```
<SValue id="ListCreator">
    <SValue id="1">
        <NValue id="SortDescending" value="true"/>
        <SValue id="TableWriter" value="Pdf"/>
    </SValue>
    <SValue id="2">
        <NValue id="SortDescending" value="false"/>
        <SValue id="TableWriter" value="Xls"/>
    </SValue>
</SValue>
```

3) Be prepared to receive an array instead (code):

```
ListCreator[] creators = config.getValue("ListCreator");
```

You decide the number and alternatives in the descriptor;
the entries arrive in the defined order. This works similar for multiple dimensions (e.g. "[][][]"). You can add alternative table writers with further parameters in the future or change the current parameters without code changes on the caller side. Just make sure the classes are all available, and to test it. There are some sources of error (typos).